Last Bits of Proof of the Compactness Theorem in Propositional Logic
I am reading the proof of compactness theorem for the propositional logic and the last part of the proof is left as exercise 2 of section 1.7 in the book by Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic. Here is the question.

Let $\Delta$ be a set of Well-Formed-Formulas (WFFs) such that every finite subset of $\Delta$ is satisfiable, and for every WFF $\alpha$, either $\alpha \in \Delta$ or $(\neg \alpha) \in \Delta$. Define the truth assignment
$$
v(A) := \begin{cases}
T & A \in \Delta \\
F & A \not\in \Delta
\end{cases},
$$
for each sentence symbol $A$. Show that for every WFF $\gamma$, we have $\bar v(\gamma) = T$ if and only if $\gamma \in \Delta$. This is part of the proof of the compactness theorem. (Hint: Use induction on $\gamma$).

As suggested, we proceed by generalized induction. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all sentence symbols, and let $\mathcal{P} = \{\neg, \land \}$ be the set of operations which is adequate, and let $I(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{P})$ be the inductive set of all WFFs made by $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{P}$.

Induction Base. Suppose that $\gamma \in \mathcal{A}$. It then follows that $\bar v(\gamma) = v(\gamma) = T$, which holds if and only if $\gamma \in \Delta$, by using the definition of $v$.

Induction Step. Assume the claim holds for WFFs $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We shall consider the following cases.



If $\gamma = (\neg \alpha)$, then we can write
\begin{align}
\bar v((\neg \alpha)) = T &\iff \bar v(\alpha) = F \tag{by truth table}\\
&\iff \alpha \not\in \Delta \tag{by induction hypothesis} \\
&\iff (\neg \alpha) \in \Delta \tag{by construction of $\Delta$}
\end{align}

If $\gamma = (\alpha \land \beta)$, we get
\begin{align}
\bar v((\alpha \land \beta)) = T &\iff \bar v(\alpha) = T \text{ and } \bar{v}(\beta) = T \tag{by truth table}\\
&\iff \alpha \in \Delta \text{ and } \beta \in \Delta \tag{by induction hypothesis} \\
\end{align}


How can I get further?

From where you get stuck, you can prove by contradiction that $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Delta$ if and only if $\alpha \land \beta \in \Delta$.
$\Rightarrow:$ Suppose that $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Delta$ but $\alpha \land \beta \notin \Delta$. By definition of $\Delta$, this means that $\lnot (\alpha \land \beta) \in \Delta$. Consider then the finite subset $\{\alpha, \ \beta, \ \lnot (\alpha \land \beta)\}$ of $\Delta$: it should be satisfiable by definition of $\Delta$, but this is impossible. Hence, $\alpha \land \beta \in \Delta$.
$\Leftarrow:$ Suppose that $\alpha \land \beta \in \Delta$ but $\alpha \notin \Delta$ or $\beta \notin \Delta$.
Without loss of generality, suppose $\alpha \notin \Delta$ (the case $\beta \notin \Delta$ is analogous).
By definition of $\Delta$, this means that $\lnot\alpha \in \Delta$. Consider then the finite subset $\{\lnot \alpha, \ \alpha \land \beta\}$ of $\Delta$: it should be satisfiable by definition of $\Delta$, but this is impossible. Hence, $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Delta$.
